# How to center a link using CSS

Tags: html, css, text, alignment, center

I am very new and was messing around with some code ( just HTML and CSS ) But I can't get my link to center like my text? The id's are just for practice I know They aren't required.

http://pastebin.com/kYyR6WUx

Answer (score 9):

I provided a solution with css. You could take a look at this link http://jsfiddle.net/qPAfK/

```
div {
    width: 100px;
}

div a {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Im doing to W3 tutorial will they talk about that "div" function?

Comment: You can just treat it like a container. Or you can try without the div.

Comment: a `<div></div>` is not a function is an element of the DOM (Document Object Modeling) they are rendered by the browser when it reads the HTML (HyperText Markup Langage) a `<div></div>` is similar to `<p></p>`, `<a></a>`, `<input/>` etc... in the way that they are elements which can be modified, added or removed and they help us give a layout to our page. CSS (Cascading Style Sheets) let us give properties to these elements allowing us to make them nice and place them where we want them to be.

Answer (score 0):

In your Case

```
 #W3link
    {
    width:100px; /*use your preferred width*/
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    }
```

Use **Class** if you want to use more than one time.

Answer (score 0):

Link is an inline element. Bootstrap uses `center-block` to change inline element display:

```
.center-block {
  display: block;
  margin-right:auto;
  margin-left:auto;
}
```

Yet this doesn't work when applied directly to link, such as:

```
<a href="#" class="center-block">link</a>
```

It only works if I apply `width` style. 20% works well in my page. This is approximate centering. I've tried `text-center` many times with links and have never been able to make it work. What surprises me is that using `display: block` alone doesn't work with `margin` centering. `Width` has to be added.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it worked for me:

`<div style="text-align:center"><a href="https://stackoverflow.com/"></a></div>`